# Public key encryption using metamask on solidity smart contract

Tags: solidity, metamask, signature, public-key, encryption

**Questions:**

1. In Solidity, how can we fetch the encrypted public key for the wallet directly from the smart contract using solidity? I have managed to retrieve it using JavaScript, but I need to know how we can use this functionality within the Solidity smart contract itself. The JavaScript function used for the retrieval can be found here: https://docs.metamask.io/wallet/reference/eth_getencryptionpublickey
2. How can we encrypt a message using the 'x25519-xsalsa20-poly1305' version directly within a Solidity smart contract? I've successfully accomplished this in JavaScript, as shown in the code snippet below, Do we have a similar method in Solidity?

```
javascript
import sigUtil from '@metamask/eth-sig-util';
const value = sigUtil.encrypt({ publicKey: key, data: msg, version: 'x25519-xsalsa20-poly1305' });
const buf = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(value), 'utf8');
const returnValue = '0x' + buf.toString('hex');
```

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> In Solidity, how can we fetch the encrypted public key for the wallet directly from the smart contract using solidity?

You cannot.

> How can we encrypt a message using the 'x25519-xsalsa20-poly1305' version directly within a Solidity smart contract?

You cannot.